# Chrome Extension doesn't inject content script after redirect

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension that interacts with Twitter and injects a content script when the user visits twitter.com/home. I declared content_scripts in manifest.json and everything works fine on twitter.com/home. However, when I visit twitter.com it redirects to twitter.com/home and the extension does not inject the content script. Adding "twitter.com" to the "matches" list in manifest.json solves the problem but I want the extension to inject the script only when twitter.com/home loads. I am considering using webNavigation API to detect redirects but I wonder if there are more efficient ways to achieve this. Thanks!

manifest.json

```
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "abc",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://twitter.com/home", "https://twitter.com/"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter is loading the page via ajax, not page reloading. thus, when you click items on the page, page content changed, URL changed. but the page actually does not reload, that's why your content scripts not working.

do this:
change your `matches` to `https://twitter.com/*`. this will make the content scripts injects to all twitter pages.

in your content script `script.js`, you need to add some logic to detect if the user is on the `home` page. 
since the page is not reloading, you need to use something like [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect page content changing(like if the `home` link is highlighted). so that your script knows the current page is `home` page and does something you want to do.